# How to regenerate records in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in sql server which has 5 columns named A, B, C, D and E. The data is shown below.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 16 | 2022-10-01 | 31 | 41 |
| 12 | 21 | 2022-10-01 | 43 | 34 |
| 13 | 28 | 2022-10-01 | 57 | 54 |
| 14 | 32 | 2022-10-01 | 41 | 49 |
| 15 | 52 | 2022-10-01 | 38 | 19 |

I should make the copy of this data for each date starting from 2022-10-01 till 2023-02-01. Only the column 'C' should change.
My expected output should have 5*120 records [5 is number of records now, 120 is number of days between Oct 1,2022 and Feb 1,2023.]

Expected sample output:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 16 | 2022-10-01 | 31 | 41 |
| 12 | 21 | 2022-10-01 | 43 | 34 |
| 13 | 28 | 2022-10-01 | 57 | 54 |
| 14 | 32 | 2022-10-01 | 41 | 49 |
| 15 | 52 | 2022-10-01 | 38 | 19 |
| 11 | 16 | 2022-10-02 | 31 | 41 |
| 12 | 21 | 2022-10-02 | 43 | 34 |
| 13 | 28 | 2022-10-02 | 57 | 54 |
| 14 | 32 | 2022-10-02 | 41 | 49 |
| 15 | 52 | 2022-10-02 | 38 | 19 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 11 | 16 | 2023-02-01 | 31 | 41 |
| 12 | 21 | 2023-02-01 | 43 | 34 |
| 13 | 28 | 2023-02-01 | 57 | 54 |
| 14 | 32 | 2023-02-01 | 41 | 49 |
| 15 | 52 | 2023-02-01 | 38 | 19 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide example DDL/DML it's a good idea to make it easily reproducible. I favor using table variables for this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (A INT, B INT, C DATE, D INT, E INT);
INSERT INTO @Table (A, B, C, D, E) VALUES 
(11, 16, '2022-10-01', 31, 41),
(12, 21, '2022-10-01', 43, 34),
(13, 28, '2022-10-01', 57, 54),
(14, 32, '2022-10-01', 41, 49),
(15, 52, '2022-10-01', 38, 19);
```

A easy way to get what you're looking for is to create a pseudo calendar table, and then cross join it to your table:

```
;WITH DateRange AS (
SELECT MIN(C) AS Date, '2023-02-01' AS mDate
  FROM @Table
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,Date), mDate
  FROM DateRange
 WHERE Date < mDate
)

SELECT A, B, Date, D, E
  FROM @Table t
    CROSS APPLY DateRange
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

| A | B | Date | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 16 | 2022-10-01 | 31 | 41 |
| 12 | 21 | 2022-10-01 | 43 | 34 |
| 13 | 28 | 2022-10-01 | 57 | 54 |
| 14 | 32 | 2022-10-01 | 41 | 49 |
| 15 | 52 | 2022-10-01 | 38 | 19 |
| 11 | 16 | 2022-10-02 | 31 | 41 |
| 12 | 21 | 2022-10-02 | 43 | 34 |
| 13 | 28 | 2022-10-02 | 57 | 54 |
| 14 | 32 | 2022-10-02 | 41 | 49 |
| 15 | 52 | 2022-10-02 | 38 | 19 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 11 | 16 | 2023-01-31 | 31 | 41 |
| 12 | 21 | 2023-01-31 | 43 | 34 |
| 13 | 28 | 2023-01-31 | 57 | 54 |
| 14 | 32 | 2023-01-31 | 41 | 49 |
| 15 | 52 | 2023-01-31 | 38 | 19 |
| 11 | 16 | 2023-02-01 | 31 | 41 |
| 12 | 21 | 2023-02-01 | 43 | 34 |
| 13 | 28 | 2023-02-01 | 57 | 54 |
| 14 | 32 | 2023-02-01 | 41 | 49 |
| 15 | 52 | 2023-02-01 | 38 | 19 |

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a date table that has one row for each date you need (there are plenty of ways to create that) and then join that against your original table without any join statement. This will make a (usually undesirable) cartesian product of all the rows in both tables. In this case this is exactly what you want.

Shown below (using postgreSQL syntax) for the first 5 dates. The "::date" part is postgreSQL's way of casting strings to dates, so you can ignore that part. This general approach will work for any relational database.

```
create table my_table (a int, b int, c date, d int, e int);

insert into my_table values 

insert into my_table values (11,    16, '2022-10-01'::date, 31, 41);
insert into my_table values (12,    21, '2022-10-01'::date, 43, 34);
insert into my_table values (13,    28, '2022-10-01'::date, 57, 54);
insert into my_table values (14,    32, '2022-10-01'::date, 41, 49);
insert into my_table values (15,    52, '2022-10-01'::date, 38, 19);

create table dates (date_column date);

insert into dates values ('2022-10-01'::date);
insert into dates values ('2022-10-02'::date);
insert into dates values ('2022-10-03'::date);
insert into dates values ('2022-10-04'::date);
insert into dates values ('2022-10-05'::date);

select a.a, a.b, b.date_column as c, a.d, a.e
from my_table as a, dates as b
order by 3, 1;
```

results:

```
a   b   c   d   e
11  16  2022-10-01  31  41
12  21  2022-10-01  43  34
13  28  2022-10-01  57  54
14  32  2022-10-01  41  49
15  52  2022-10-01  38  19
11  16  2022-10-02  31  41
12  21  2022-10-02  43  34
13  28  2022-10-02  57  54
14  32  2022-10-02  41  49
15  52  2022-10-02  38  19
11  16  2022-10-03  31  41
12  21  2022-10-03  43  34
...
13  28  2022-10-05  57  54
14  32  2022-10-05  41  49
15  52  2022-10-05  38  19
```

You don't actually need to create a physical table, a view will probably work well for your use case.

```
create or replace view my_view as
    select a.a, a.b, b.date_column as c, a.d, a.e
    from my_table as a, dates as b
    order by 3, 1;
```